# Fully-faithful functors between categories of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, functors

Let $f\colon A\to B$ be an injective homomorphism of associative rings. It induces the faithful functor $F\colon B\text{-mod} \to A\text{-mod}.$ Are there any known conditions on $f$ for $F$ to be full (i.e. the $B$-mod is a full subcategory of $A$-mod)?

Comment: that might help! https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05G3

Comment: I get the feeling it should be related to $f$ being an epimorphism of rings, but I don't have a solid argument.

Comment: @CaptainLama, it is too strict condition. I want $f$ to be injective, so if it is also an epimorphism, then $f$ is just an isomorphism.

Comment: No, you have the wrong idea about epimorphisms of rings. Surjective morphisms are indeed epimorphisms, but epimorphisms are much more complicated than that. For instance the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: $F$ is always faithful, regardless of whether $f$ is injective.

Comment: @CaptainLama, ok, sorry. There is a notion of homological epimorphism, which is a morphism, that induces fully faithful functor on **derived** categories. So maybe an epimorphism has a similar characterizing property.